# Java executable jar location best practice for systemd and Jenkins CI?

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, systemd

I have Spring Boot 2 executable jar (*runs by command java -jar myapp.jar*) which I need to deploy to remote **linux** server as systemd service. Jenkins CI will manage building this jar from source and copy to proper location and restart java service associated with `myapp.jar`. Linux server has just one user '**jonas**' with *sudo privilege*, in addition to **jenkins** user.  Where do I need to put `myapp.jar` on **linux** server from security best practice point of view in production environment ? Possible location:

```
 /var/myapplications/myapp.jar 
 /home/jona/myapplications/myapp.jar
 /opt//myapplications/myapp.jar
```

Also where the log files generated by `myapp.jar` are going to be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, I would recommend to keep all third parties and applications under `/opt/{{ app_name }}`

You can follow if you like following structure which makes deployment of new artefacts much easier with option to quickly rollback if needed.

`/opt/{{ app_name }}/releases/{{ app_version }}`

`/opt/{{ app_name }}/current` <- Symlink to above

`/opt/{{ app_name }}/current/logs` <- directory for logs which would be part of the `releases/{{ app_version }}`

Your deployment script can create respective folders, manage permissions and symlinks for this purpose.

What i personally like is to make sure it runs under a non-privileged user with proper permissions to ensure only that particular user can read/execute/write on the directory recursively which would include logs which might have some sensitive information that might be included as part of the exception, however this purely depends on how you log.

Comment: Usman by non-priviiged user you mean non-root user? So in my case jonas is non privileged user? If not do I need to create another user x who just has access to only specified folders and the app would run as that user x? In this case I also need to login as  user x in order to view log files? or I can login as jonas and view log files? Also not sure how jenkins user would deploy and manage the app if app is accessible only for that non-priviliged user x. Thanks

Comment: So in this case the user `jonas` is a non-privileged user (non-root) which i assume will be used to run the application, i would recommend to create a group called `jonasapp` or however you would like to name it, add `jenkins` and `jonas` user to that group and then assign permissions for the group part respectively

For `jonas` user if app is running from that user then it will be able to access the log, read permissions to the group `jonasapp` users under that group can read logs aswell

`jenkins` user can be added to that group as apparently it appears both are running on the same host.